# How to convert key ti index in codigniter

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to do something like this...
I had an array structure like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_id1] => 15
            [product_id2] => 14
            [product_id3] => 0
            [product_id4] => 0
            [product_id5] => 0
        )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [product_id1] => 15
        [product_id2] => 14
        [product_id3] => 0
        [product_id4] => 0
        [product_id5] => 0
    )

)
```

and i want to convert it to

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 14
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [0] => 15
        [1] => 14
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do:

```
$new = array_values( (array) $arr[0] );
print_r($new);
```

added:

```
$final_arr = array();
foreach( $arr as $val ) {
    $tmpArr = array_values( (array)$val);
    $final_arr[] = (object) $tmpArr; //convert to object again
}
```

Comment: hey when i am using your above code its working but when i am converting it back to object its not working...

Comment: @NitishMahna can you clear what you mean by "converting it back to object"..? the code below "added" should work isnt it ..?

Comment: I mean your second code which you have written later is not working

Comment: I had one more query, if we have to print only the 1st index i.e $final_arr[0]->1; so how we will do that???